# delete certain parts of a text text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

let's say I have some divs that contain an example text

```
  <div>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel ante diam. Donec vitae magna metus.
 </div>
```

how could I delete with javascript only the text that is before the first point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split the text with point, remove the index 0 then put the rest in to div again. Example:

```js
var elem=document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var text=elem.textContent.split('.');

delete text[0];

elem.textContent=text.toString();
```

```html
<div>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel ante diam. Donec vitae magna metus.
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to split the string into an array on the period character, then reassemble the string omitting the first element.

```
var origStringArray = origString.split('.');  // Create Array
origStringArray.shift()                       // Remove First Element
var newString= origStringArray.join('.');     // Join array into string
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, I'll provide a function that will delete the text after you call it, also included with button. If you want to delete it with other method, just call the function with something like `onclick="deletetxt()"`

#### Code:

```js
function deletetxt() {
  document.getElementById("texttodelete").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="texttodelete">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel ante diam. Donec vitae magna metus.
</div>
<br />
<button onclick="deletetxt()">Delete</button>
<br />
<br />
<div onclick="deletetxt()">You can also delete with div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it javascript, or jquery

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('.deletetext').text('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='deletetext'>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel ante diam. Donec vitae magna metus.
 </div>
 <button>deleting text
 </button>
```